# PostGIS: Select FROM AS with WHERE not working

Tags: postgis

Maybe it's just because it's a Friday afternoon, but why can't I use the last WHERE in the following query? The ORDER BY works, but when I include the WHERE, I get an error saying "column line_geom does not exist".

```
SELECT ST_AsText(ST_Intersection(the_geom,ST_MakeEnvelope(...))) as line_geom 
FROM (
  SELECT the_geom FROM table WHERE time > '2013-09-01'
) AS foo
-- WHERE GeometryType(line_geom) = 'LINESTRING'
ORDER BY line_geom
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this has to do with the order in which the query is evaluated.  Basically, 'line_geom' does not exist until after the function in the select clause has been evaluated.  This happens after the where clause is evaluated, but before the order by clause.

Also, you seem to be using GeometryType on a text (result of ST_AsText).  I think you mean to have the_geom in the where clause.

try:

```
SELECT ST_AsText(ST_Intersection(the_geom,ST_MakeEnvelope(...))) as line_geom 
FROM (
  SELECT the_geom FROM table WHERE time > '2013-09-01'
) AS foo
WHERE GeometryType(the_geom) = 'LINESTRING'
ORDER BY line_geom
```

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your quick reply. All of the_geom values are LINESTRING, but the output from ST_Intersection contains LINESTRING , MULTILINESTRING, and GEOMETRYCOLLECTION EMPTY. Modifying the query to use the_geom does not appear to filter the output (line_geom).

Comment: You were right about the order - wrapping it in another SELECT * FROM () as foo2 WHERE GeometryType(line_geom) = 'LINESTRING' made it work. Thanks again for your answer.

Comment: PostgreSQL doesn't support column aliases in `WHERE` clause, repeating `ST_AsText(ST_Intersection(the_geom,ST_MakeEnvelope(...)))` in the where clause would do it.